# making directory shortcuts like $HOME

Tags: macos, terminal

On the mac, is there a way to make shortcuts like $HOME, instead of using alias?

With alias, I just want the `$HOME` for example, and not the "cd" in front so to speak

stox

Answer (score 0):

`HOME` is a really bad choice, since many programs will use the value of `HOME` to find the home directory.  However, you certainly can do

```
#WARNING: this is a bad idea.  It would be better to choose a 
#name other than "HOME"
HOME="cd /p/a/t/h"
$HOME
```

Using a function would be more reliable and flexible, but it's certainly possible to put a command in a variable like this.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion would be to use the **.profile** file to define a global function:

1. Navigate to your user home directory in Terminal
2. Type `nano .profile` (likely it doesn't exist yet)
3. Create a function, for example *goHome*, like so:

```
goHome() {
 ... paste command here
}
```

Finally, save the file (using Ctrl+X).

Now you can pretty much type `goHome()` anywhere in the Terminal to execute the function, making it a really powerfull feature for creating functions and shortcuts for tedious operations.